# ,Net Core MVC Multi Browser Sign out

Tags: .net

i have developed application using Identity Server 4 .Net Core, i logged in different browsers, now once i logout from one browser i should be able to logout from all the different browser.

since the browser do not share cookie i am facing hurdle, how can i identify the common linkage among browser

Comment: I think Identity Server should validate the ongoing sessions off all browsers and when invalid you should clear the session? [like discussed here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2542)

Answer (score 0):

Given that each client browser has its own cookies (logging in from multiple browsers saves a cookie in each browser  - assuming different devices and different browsers - opening a tab in the same browser will still count as being logged in). This is what you have found.

When a user logs out from one browser, the cookie on another allows them to stay logged in. As far as I am aware, Identity does not store anything useful on the database when a user logs in or logs out. All it does is match user credentials at logon with the database hashes and creates the cookies.

If you want to have some mechanism that goes beyond the normal - as you are suggesting, you can additional C# code and SQL tables to monitor each login/logout, possibly matching up some cookie value such as a GUID that you store. Then, logging out from one browser will clear your Identity tables. Since users can log in from multiple devices you will need multiple LoginId values - so a separate table with login/out dates might be useful